# starting activity on imagebutton click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i have tried implement simple stuff to start new activity on imagebutton click "Dealsofday" is my imagebutton name...
here is my 
1)mainactiviy.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButtondod();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void addListenerOnButtondod() {

    final Context context = this;

    ImageButton btndod = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Dealsofday);

    btndod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Spldeals.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });
}

}
```

2)Spldeals.java is as below

```
public class Spldeals extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spldeals);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_spldeals, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

and my log looks as below

```
03-08 00:22:38.697: D/dalvikvm(477): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 678 objects / 52432 bytes in 87ms
03-08 00:22:42.777: I/dalvikvm(477): Could not find method com.example.test.Spldeals.getActionBar, referenced from method com.example.test.Spldeals.onCreate
03-08 00:22:42.777: W/dalvikvm(477): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3320: Lcom/example/test/Spldeals;.getActionBar ()Landroid/app/ActionBar;
03-08 00:22:42.788: D/dalvikvm(477): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0009
03-08 00:22:42.797: D/dalvikvm(477): VFY: dead code 0x000c-0011 in Lcom/example/test/Spldeals;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
03-08 00:22:42.878: D/AndroidRuntime(477): Shutting down VM
03-08 00:22:42.878: W/dalvikvm(477): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.test.Spldeals.getActionBar
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at com.example.test.Spldeals.onCreate(Spldeals.java:15)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-08 00:22:42.897: E/AndroidRuntime(477):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

it is ok with first screen and it is loaded properly but when i click the imagebutton(Dealsofday) the app stops unexpectedly
please help.

Comment: post the code of Spldeals class.

Comment: what is your `android:minSdkVersion` in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: in your layout file(xml) your have mention `onclick:`  under imagebutton so can you post that xml code

Comment: @niculare it shows current minimum is 8

Comment: what would happen if i remove

Comment: getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Comment: @KaranMer see my answer which i posted.

Comment: i did something like this in manifest<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Comment: but it still shows the error with getActionBar()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

You are trying to run your app on an Android version in which the ActionBar doesn't exist, that is below API 11.

Comment: Clean the project and build it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `android:minSdkVersion` lower than 11, the method `getActionBar()` is not available, so try to set in `AndroidManifest.xml` `android:minSdkVersion=11` or greater.

The method `getActionBar()` is available only since API 11.